# Creating a Blank Rails 3.1 Templating Handler

Tags: markup, ruby-on-rails-3.1, templating, actionview

What I want to do is make it just output the view itself, and ignore what Rails would normally think is embedded Ruby within the HTML.

For example:

```
<div class="current">
  <div class="question">
   <h3 id="homework_name"><%= homework.name %><h3 id="due">Due <%= homework.due %></h3></h3>
    <h2 class="title">The Question:</h2>
    <p id="question_contents"class="contents"><%= current_question.contents</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <h2 class="title">Your Answer:</h2>
    <textarea class="contents" id="student_answer"><%= current_question.answer %></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want an ActionView Template Handler to ignore all mentions of:

- `<%= homework.name %>`
- `<%= homework.due %>`
- `<%= current_question.contents %>`
- `<%= current_question.answer %>`

More specifically, it should **ignore any tags starting with `<%` and ending with `%>`**

If you need more info check out http://pastie.org/private/epsxnapldho6co2y0indg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go https://gist.github.com/1144297

And use .html.lifo extensions for your templates.